# UIWebView in background stops the music

Tags: swift, background, uiwebview, background-process

This is my code, i´m using a uiwebview to load a web page and listen music, but when y pless the home button, the music stops. How can i allow to continous working in the backgroud.

Here is my code.

```
var webView: UIWebView!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationItem.title = "Desdeelcanton.com"
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    super.viewDidLoad()
    webView = UIWebView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    webView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(webView)
    if let url = URL(string: "http://desdeelcanton.com") {
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.loadRequest(request)

            }
    let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(appMovedToBackground), name: Notification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive, object: nil)

        }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func appMovedToBackground() {
    print("App moved to background!")
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background audio playback in UIWebView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482544/background-audio-playback-in-uiwebview)